# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in PHP-Java bridge

Tags: java, php, tomcat, classnotfoundexception, php-java-bridge

I am working on PHP-Java Bridge.

A syntax from my php file looks as follows:

```
require_once("java/Java.inc");
$address = new Java('com.odus.apg.cfa.java.address');
```

I have placed the package file cfa.jar which consist *com/odus/apg/cfa/java/address.class* file in **TOMCAT.HOME/webapps/JavaBridge/WEB-INF/lib**

And my php file is located at **TOMCAT.HOME/webapps/JavaBridge**

After this set-up I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new com.odus.apg.cfa.java.address. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.odus.apg.cfa.java.address VM: 1.7.0_40@http://java.oracle.com/" at: #-18 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) #-17 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) #-16 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) #-15 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) #-14 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) #-13 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) #-12 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) #-11 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) #-10 java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) #-9 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518) #-8 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445) #-7 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458) #-6 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500) #-5 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.handleRequests(JavaBridge.java:150) #-4 php in /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc on line 195
```

Is this set-up even correct? Are the jar files and php files located in correct directories? How can this error be resolved?

Comment: Are you sure this is a class: `com.odus.apg.cfa.java.address`? It looks like a package to me.

Comment: the class file address.class in inside of cfa.jar

Comment: Okay. Classes in Java should be in `PascalCase` - so `Address`. But that isn't the problem, it's just (very) confusing.

Comment: It seems that php file is unable to locate the cfa.jar Is there any syntax in java to reference these jar files

Comment: just a tomcat restart fixed the problem in my case, as tomcat/java Bridge indexes jars on startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, I think your php file is correctly coded. What you need to do is this :

`sudo chown yourprofile:yourprofile -R TOMCAT.HOME/webapps/JavaBridge/WEB-INF/lib/cfa.jar`

After this command restart your tomcat server using `shutdown.sh` and then `startup.sh`
Also, restart the apache webserver using `sudo service apache2 restart`

Ensure that the command in the php file is actually exactly in the same case as per the class names in the jar file and path is also correct.

I agree with Boris that `$address = new Java('com.odus.apg.cfa.java.address');` should actually be something like `$address = new Java('com.odus.apg.cfa.java.Address');`

The problem can be sometimes with the permissions rather than the path, naming etc.